# How to use NLog in C++?

Tags: visual-c++, logging, nlog

I have  a simple native ++ console application in visual C++.

In order to use NLog there is a mixed mode " "NLogC.dll"

- How can i add "NLogC.dll" to my application
- And use for logging?

> Simply how can i use Nlog in a native C++ Application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NLog includes a header file (`NLogC.h`) and import library (`NLogC.lib`). Those should be used to use the library.

Add the path to the include file (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\NLog\.NET Framework 4.0\NLogC\include`) to the include path, either globally or for the project only. You can specify it in the project's properties under "Additional Include Directories" under Configuration Properties, C/C++, General. Add the path to the library file (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\NLog\.NET Framework 4.0\NLogC\x86`; make sure to pick x86 or x64 based on the architecture you're targeting) to the library path ("Additional Library Directories" under Configuration Properties, Linker, General).

Add the `NLogC.lib` file to the project's libraries (add it to "Additional Dependencies" under Configuration Properties, Linker, Input).

Then, you can use the API like this:

```
#include <cstdarg> // Needed for va_list type, which NLogC.h requires
#include <NLogC.h>

int main()
{
    NLog_Info(L"Test", L"TestMessage");

    return 0;
}
```

Make sure you put `NLogC.dll`, `NLog.dll`, and a suitable configuration file in the same directory as your executable.

Note that this is really only intended to be used when you have native components as part of a larger, managed application, or are transitioning from native to managed. If your application is pure C++, there are likely more suitable native logging libraries that don't require loading the CLR just to do logging.