# NLog in mixed C#\C++ Application

Tags: c#, c++, nlog

We are using NLog in our solution, which is primarily a C# application.  We do however have a native C++ DLL project and a managed C++ DLL project that wraps it.  We would like to be able to log from those projects to NLog like we do throughout the rest of the application.

I found some hints online that this was possible, but all the trails went cold.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9213528/2212458

Does anyone know if this is possible or how to proceed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was supported in NLog 2 (called NLogC).

The support for it had been dropped in NLog 3: http://nlog-project.org/2013/12/14/nlog-3-0.html

Comment: Thanks.  I see it now on the 2.1 tag.  Wonder if it will work if I build it.

Comment: It works!  You can just take the NLogC project from the 2.1 tag, build it, and use it with the current NLog release (I used the one from Nuget).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just add a C++/Interop-Helper-project to your solution, that 
implements an abstract C++ logging-interface, that calls into the .NET NLog-methods.

Then the Helper-project will work as interface between the C#-application and the existing C++ DLL-project. It will initialize the C++ DLL and give the abstract C++ logging-interface to the C++ DLL.

With this method, then you can use any version of NLog.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually able to use NLog from a Managed C++ project and I haven't seen any other examples of this working.  In fact, I don't think it's supported by the NLog development team.  But it's nice to be able to add logging to a Managed C++ project.  If you want instructions, I can provide it.  If you're looking for a solution for an NLog solution for native C++, there was an older version 2.0 that supported it.  See this example: [How to use NLog in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077478/how-to-use-nlog-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is the code I'm running in a CLR console app VS 2013 with NLog 4.0.0:

```
using namespace NLog;

NLog::Logger^ LO = nullptr;
NLog::LogManager^ LM = nullptr;
LO = LM->GetCurrentClassLogger();
LO->Debug("Ha");
```